# missing "search" arguments in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have this in my batchfile and that works. My problem is that i use it on diffrent computers and they does not store "symatech" the same way.

```
@ECHO === Checking for Symantech Products
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files\Symantec" GOTO DoneSymantec
ECHO One moment while we remove Symantec Software...
Call "%~d0\exe\Norton_Removal_Tool.exe"
:DoneSymantec
```

So my question is, is there a way to have it like this: if not exist ***any folder contain norton or symantech** in  program files goto donesymantech

Comment: +1 for worthiness-of-purpose...

Answer (score 0):

`dir /b /s /ad "c:\program files\symantec` will search recursive for a folder "symantec", starting in "c:\program files"

Check `%errorlevel%`, it will be `0` if found, `1`, if not found.

Theoretical you can start in "C:\", but that would take a quite long time to finish.
It is much faster, if you know where to start the search ("c:\program files" in your example)

If needed, start a second search in "C:\Program Files (x86)" instead of only one search over the whole disk.

If you don't want to see the output of `dir`, just redirect it to nirwana (`>nul`). This will also quicken the search, because printing to the screen is quite slow.

EDIT: if you should need the path instead of only knowing "if exist":

```
for /F "delims=" %%j in ('dir /b /s /ad "c:\Program Files\symantec" "c:\Program Files (x86)\symantec"') do @echo %%j
```

(searches in "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)"; adapt as needed)

Comment: I recommend to use %ProgramFiles% and %ProgramFiles(x86)% to make script drive & language portable